# awk FPAT to ignore commas in csv

Tags: csv, awk, sed

### Sample.csv Data

```
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",vodka,ZETA+GLOBAL 4(ID: ZETA+GLOBAL),,105629,523,flag
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",vodka,Captify (ID: Captify),,94676,884,flag
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",vodka,QuantCast (ID: QuantCast),,46485,786,flag
TerrorViolencetest,germany,QuantCast (ID: QuantCast),,31054,491,flag
EY-Keyword-Blacklist,BBQ,MIQ+RON (ID: MIQ+RON),,26073,149,flag
TerrorViolencetest,chips,Captify (ID: Captify),,23737,553,flag
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",bacon,QuantCast (ID: QuantCast),,17461,241,flag
VurityAdult-1test,cracks,Captify (ID: Captify),,17325,358,flag
VurityAdult-1test,pizza+grills,Captify (ID: Captify),,15173,41,flag
```

### Desired Output

```
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",vodka,ZETA+GLOBAL (ID: ZETA+GLOBAL),105629,523,flag
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",vodka,Captify (ID: Captify),94676,884,flag
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",vodka,QuantCast (ID: QuantCast),46485,786,flag
TerrorViolencetest,germany,QuantCast (ID: QuantCast),31054,491,flag
EY-Keyword-Blacklist,BBQ,MIQ+RON (ID: MIQ+RON),26073,149,flag
TerrorViolencetest,chips,Captify (ID: Captify),23737,553,flag
"2-Keyw-Bllist, TerrorViolencetest",bacon,QuantCast (ID: QuantCast),17461,241,flag
VurityAdult-1test,cracks,Captify (ID: Captify),17325,358,flag
VurityAdult-1test,pizza+grills,Captify (ID: Captify),15173,41,flag
```

### Issue

I have 7 columns of data and am able to print out/ remove the columns needed for the desired output (if it worked). However due to the hard commas in the middle of my data in column 1, `awk` believes I have more than 7 columns and when I try to remove column 4 it removes values it shouldn't as some rows get shunted over into columns they shouldn't be.

### What I've Tried

- I've tried to pipe results from `csvtool` (which is able to confirm columns correctly) and use `sed/awk` to sub the commas for something else. This fails I guess due to the fact the other commands don't understand what csvtool knows for columns.
- I've tried to work awk's `FPAT` but from what I was able to work out online, I can get my desired output but my script only seems to print the final row of my data.

`awk -F"," -v OFS=',' 'BEGIN {FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} END {print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7}' sample.csv`

Does anyone know of an easier way to get my columns understood for when I remove columns or is `FPAT` the only way to go with this and I'm missing something with what I've done?

Comment: If you're using csvtool, why not just use that to remove the column? `csvtool sample.csv remove 4`.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I need to be able to get a tool to understand the column placements as I intend to split my data into separate files based on column 3's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F"," -v OFS=',' 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} {print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7}' Input_file
```

OR make better use of `BEGIN` :)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} {print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7}' Input_file
```

Reason why OP's code is partially working: Since you are using `END` block and printing everything there that is the reason it is printing last row (though this behavior is not defined in few of `awk` AFAIK). How `END` block works is:

***There are 3 main BLOCKS in `awk`:***

1. `BEGIN` BLOCK: Which runs before any Input_file is being read, it is important when you want to initialize variables we can do it before program starts reading actual Input_file.
2. `{...}` main BLOCK: Now comes the main block where all Input_file records(lines) will be read.
3. `END` BLOCK: `END` block of any `awk` program is executed once program is done with reading whole Input_file, so all kind of calculations eg--> with arrays, printing last values after processing of complete Input_file will be done here.

***What `man awk` says:***

> Finally, after all the input is exhausted, gawk executes the code in
>   the END rule(s) (if any).

Comment: I can confirm this worked. I've got a delay before I can accept your answer but will do so. Thanks for confirming where I was going wrong, I clearly mixed up my understanding of the `END` block and was treating it like a ` | ` but within an awk set up