# Process non common csv file with awk using field patterns

Tags: regex, csv, awk

My bank sends a non common CSV file using `;` as field separator and a binary code (hexadecimal `a0` or octal `240`) to enclose the fields where a `;` could occur, as below:

**Input**

```
Extrait;Date;Date valeur;Compte;Description;Montant;Devise
�2020/0001/0002�;29.02.2020;29.02.2020;-;�28/02/20 Some shop in Antwerp     A Antwerpen (BE)�;-16,50;EUR
�2020/0001/0001�;01.02.2020;01.02.2020;-;�31/01/20 Some shop in Zaventem    Z Zaventem (BE)�;-13,00;EUR
```

I need to process fields 2, 5 and 6 with AWK.

**Desired output**

```
{Date}{Description}{Montant}
{29.02.2020}{28/02/20 Some shop in Antwerp     A Antwerpen (BE)}{-16,50}
{01.02.2020}{31/01/20 Some shop in Zaventem    Z Zaventem (BE)}{-13,00}
```

Up to now, as long as the fields enclosed by `�` do not contain any `;` the script below using the variable `FPAT` works:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { 
  FS=";"
  FPAT="[^;]*"                        # this works but not in all cases
  #FPAT="([^;]*)|(\240[^\240]+\240)"  # this doesn't work
}
{ gsub (/\240/, "", $5)               # I wish I could skip this instruction too
  print "{" $2 "}{" $5 "}{" $6 "}" 
}
```

I found a similar case (see [awk FPAT to ignore commas in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59127981/awk-fpat-to-ignore-commas-in-csv)) but changing the `,` into `;` and the `\"` into `\240` didn't do the trick.

I need help for implementing a `FPAT` pattern to scan correctly my CSV file in all cases.

Comment: Note that the csv format isn't a standard and even if the comma as separator and the double quote as protection character are more usual, there's nothing wrong to use a semi-colon and the non-breakable space. Also, take care the non-breakable space, and probably all the file, is written with an ISO8859-1 encoding and not in UTF-8.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: OK, I will edit my question in orde to change "non standard" into "non common". I don't know if the file is encoded UTF-8 or  ISO8859-1, because I see no letters with accents.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: indeed, I saw inside of another file that my bank is encoding according to ISO8859-1. If I convert the file to UTF-8, I get the sequence `\xc2\xa0` instead of `\xa0`, which I can't use in the `FPAT` proposed by anubhava. I will have to find a workaround...

Comment: Nothing forbids to encode the result of anubhava script to UTF-8 after.

Comment: Also if you choose to convert your file before, you can change FPAT to `[^;\xc2]+(\xc2[^\xa0][^;\xc2]*)*|(\xc2[^\xa0][^;\xc2]*)+` *(without the typo)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gnu awk` with `FPAT`:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^;\xa0]+' '{printf "{%s}{%s}{%s}\n", $2, $5, $6}' file
```

```
{Date}{Description}{Montant}
{29.02.2020}{28/02/20 Some shop in Antwerp     A Antwerpen (BE)}{-16,50}
{01.02.2020}{31/01/20 Some shop in Zaventem    Z Zaventem (BE)}{-13,00}
```

`-v FPAT='[^;\xa0]+'` sets field pattern as 1+ of any character that is not `;` and not `\xa0`.

Comment: It works, thank you, but I still need to add a statement `gsub (/\xa0/, "", $5)` to get rid of the binary chars. I changed the `+` by `*` in `FPAT` for matching also empty fields.

Comment: After all, I think that setting `FPAT` to `[^;\xa0]*` will split a string enclosed into `\xa0` in two parts when it contains a `;`, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Since regex is `[^;\xa0]+` it will make a `;\xa0` a single delimiter not 2 delimiters. However I could not really figure out positions of `\xa0` from your input in question.